# Renaming files on Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Can it be done through the IDE itself? I can't find an option to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. I also checked Qt Creator 2.0alpha and didn't find anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. It is a suggested feature: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-26